# Vistual studio 2008 executaable cannot run on target system without .net frame work

Tags: c++, visual-c++

i have crated application in VS 2008 using VC console project. i execute this executable to target system which does not have VS i got error 
"The system cannot execute the specified programe."
i have also installed vcredist_x86.exe on target system but no success. i have the following test programe

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include"iostream"

using namespace std;
 int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    cout<<"hello ";
    return 0;
}
```

please help me what i am missing

Comment: Are you sure you installed the correct vcredist_x86? i.e VC 2008 or VC 2008 SP1?

Comment: what is the exact error message you see, in its entirety?

Comment: yes i have installed the vcredist_x"The system cannot execute the specified programe"

Comment: Check this out http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vssetup/thread/b947eb7f-31c8-436b-8eea-8777c7638cc5/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't try to run the Debug build of your program on another machine, only deploy the Release build.

For small programs like these, you don't have any need for the shared CRT dlls.  Right-click your project in the Solution Explorer window, Properties, C/C++, Code Generation.  Be sure the Release configuration is selected (upper left combo).  Change Runtime Library to /MT.

Comment: This is most likely the problem, the redist only contains the dlls for *release" builds...

Answer (score 0):

Anything program you create with .NET NEEDS .NET framework to be installed onto target machine.

Every single DLL that you refer to in ypur program is either to be found within the .NET GAC (global assembly cache) of the target machine, either installed together with your software. But DO NOT try to embed the entire .NET in your app, they are worth gigabytes...

Besides, MS provides for .NET lookup, download and installation within VS install process (like clickOnce etc.)

Alternatively, you could try Mono, provided you are patient... Mono mimicks .NET features, but stays several monthes (years) behind .NET! Anyway, Mono must be installed on target machine as well, and .NET is free for Windows users, so...

Comment: The OP's code looks like straight C++ to me. Not sure how .NET installation would apply here

Comment: i have not used .net class in my programe.

Comment: You can compile C++ into a .NET application, technically. But that's not something that you would do by accident.